# How to install python-pip in CentOS7 Docker Container

Tags: python, docker, pip, centos-7

I am trying to build a docker container that includes pip.

I am on CentOS 7.

Here is the fragment from running the docker build command:

```
Step 3 : RUN yum -y install python-pip
 ---> Running in 25d1ba46e6dc
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.vcu.edu
 * extras: mirror.clarkson.edu
 * updates: mirrors.unifiedlayer.com
No package python-pip available.
Error: Nothing to do
2015/02/13 19:23:48 The command [/bin/sh -c yum -y install python-pip] returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I would post my Dockerfile, but it seems that python-pip is not available from the standard CentOS distribution, because this fails too:

```
sudo yum -y install python-pip
[sudo] password for theuser: 
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.thelinuxfix.com
 * extras: mirrors.xmission.com
 * updates: mirrors.tripadvisor.com
No package python-pip available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

There is this link on solving the install problem for the host system:
http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-pip-on-centos-7/
That involves using rpm or curl.  I think that is a bit messy for Docker.

Also, if CentOS removed pip from the standard distribution, maybe they have good reason and I should not use brute force to install it.

This does not seem to be an issue in Ubuntu or other distributions.  Just CentOS 7.

My concise question is:
What is the preferred way to install pip (or an alternative) in CentOS 7?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using this in the Dockerfile allowed me to install pip:

```
RUN yum -y install epel-release && yum clean all
RUN yum -y install python-pip && yum clean all
```

That seems much cleaner than using an rpm or curl.

If that still fails, try:

```
RUN yum -y install --enablerepo="epel" python-pip && yum clean all
```

Comment: I changed it from ; to && so that if command fails it doesnt proceed.

Comment: How do you get the latest pip version. `RUN yum -y install python-pip` but I want to directly install lastest version 10 of pip instead of 8 get installed